# React navigation (Tab Navigator) with custom SVGIcons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-navigation-v5

I'm using React navigation to change screens with the bottom tab navigations, but when I try to use a custom SVG I have many troubles and using an image to show as an icon the color obviously doesn't change, how can I use an SVG file that can recognize the color im passing to change when I'm on the page?

[image]
[image]

```
function MyTabs() {
  return(
    <Tab.Navigator
    tabBarOptions={{
      showLabel: false,
      style:{
        backgroundColor:'#313A3F',
        borderTopColor: 'transparent'
      },
      activeTintColor: '#E6B056',
    }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen 
      name="ProfileScreen" 
      component={ProfileScreen} 
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
          <Ionicons name="person" size={32} color={color} />
        )
      }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen 
      name="MatchScreen" 
      component={MatchScreen} 
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <Image
              style={{ width: 38, height: 38 }}
              source={require('../images/Icons/ico-menu-busca-evas.png')}
            />
          )
      }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen 
      name="CheckIn" 
      component={CheckIn} 
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
        <FontAwesome5  name="map-marker" size={32} color={color} />
        )
      }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="ChatScreen"
      component={ChatScreen} 
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
        <Ionicons name="chatbubbles" size={32} color={color} />
        )
      }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Comment: "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "expo": "^41.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this issue using:

import Svg, { G, Path } from 'react-native-svg';

then using the original svg passing props for color and size.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer from @Renan works, I just wanted to share the full code sample.
So, like he said, first add this import...

```
import Svg, { G, Path } from 'react-native-svg';
```

after that, use it like this in your code...

```
<Svg
    width={size}
    height={size}
    viewBox='0 0 24 24'
    fillRule='evenodd'
    clipRule='evenodd'
    strokeLinejoin='round'
    strokeMiterlimit={2}
>
    <G transform='matrix(1,0,0,1,-2.99997,-1.5)'>
        <Path
            d='M13.003,14C13.553,14 14,13.544 14,13.005L14,4.995C13.997,4.449 13.549,4.002 13.003,4L6.997,4C6.447,4 6,4.456 6,4.995L6,13.005C6.003,13.551 6.451,13.998 6.997,14L13.003,14ZM13.003,23C13.553,23 14,22.562 14,21.997L14,17.003C14,16.449 13.547,16 13.003,16L6.997,16C6.996,16 6.994,16 6.993,16C6.448,16 6,16.448 6,16.993C6,16.996 6,17 6,17.003L6,21.997C6,22.551 6.453,23 6.997,23L13.003,23ZM23.003,23C23.553,23 24,22.555 24,22.004L24,12.996C23.998,12.45 23.549,12.002 23.003,12L16.997,12C16.997,12 16.996,12 16.996,12C16.45,12 16,12.45 16,12.996L16,22.004C16.002,22.55 16.451,22.998 16.997,23L23.003,23ZM16,9.01C16,9.556 16.453,10 16.997,10L23.003,10C23.553,10 24,9.549 24,9.01L24,4.99C23.996,4.446 23.547,4.001 23.003,4L16.997,4C16.453,4.001 16.005,4.446 16,4.99L16,9.01Z'
            fill={color}
        />
    </G>
</Svg>
```